# voice call via twilio and php: parse error in autoload.php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

I would like to make a voice call, using the twilio php library.
I downloaded the php helper library from the mentioned [Github](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/archive/main.zip) link on the [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/php-manual-install) website.
Then I used the php code that is provided there too:

```
    <?php
// Include the bundled autoload from the Twilio PHP Helper Library
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$auth_token = 'your_auth_token';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]

// A Twilio number you own with Voice capabilities
$twilio_number = "+15017122661";

// Where to make a voice call (your cell phone?)
$to_number = "+15558675310";

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->account->calls->create(
    $to_number,
    $twilio_number,
    array(
        "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
    )
);
```

Unfortunately I am getting the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /users/USER/www/twilio/twilio-php-main/src/Twilio/autoload.php on line 61.

I assumed that their can´t be an error in the library, and couldn´t find or solve it myself. Does somedbody have an idea?

Comment: Is your PHP version one of the supported ones? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/#supported-php-versions

Comment: Embarrassingly, that was the mistake. PHP version was set to a 5.6, I changed to 7.4 now. Afterards I had to activate the cURL functions. Thanks @CBroe !